# Sharpened versions of the Fisher information inequality?

Tags: inequalities, it.information-theory, fisher-information

Let $X, Y$ be two independent random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. In the paper [[1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/669301), see ineq. (11)], the following convolution inequality is proven for the Fisher information:
$$
I(X + Y) \preceq \Big(I(X)^{-1} + I(Y)^{-1}\Big)^{-1}, 
$$
where $I(Z)$ denotes the Fisher information of a random vector $Z \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

This inequality also holds with equality if and only if $X, Y$ are Gaussian.

Now suppose that $X$ has a fixed distribution.  When $X$ has non-Gaussian law, the inequality above is loose. Are there any sharpenings of this inequality in this case?